# Getting more disk space on Ubuntu20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, gparted, disk

I'm using a dual booting machine with Windows10 and Ubuntu20.04 (actually the windows was not booted since I have started using Ubuntu). I have tried to allocate more disk space for the Ubuntu using Gparted from live USB. I have just moved 76Gib of free space from the windows part to the Ubuntu part. Note that this free space was on the left of the Ubuntu file system, while the free space is usually shown on the right.

Now when I open the file system from the Ubuntu20.04 I cannot see any additional free space.
How can I find the new space from the Ubuntu?

BTW, I not really care about the Windows.

Output of lsblk:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0  10.2M  1 loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/104
loop2         7:2    0  99.4M  1 loop /snap/core/11420
loop3         7:3    0   217M  1 loop /snap/code/73
loop4         7:4    0  99.4M  1 loop /snap/core/11606
loop5         7:5    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2074
loop6         7:6    0 362.3M  1 loop /snap/qt513/24
loop7         7:7    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop8         7:8    0  61.7M  1 loop /snap/core20/1026
loop9         7:9    0  61.8M  1 loop /snap/core20/1081
loop10        7:10   0   6.2M  1 loop /snap/curl/233
loop11        7:11   0 295.7M  1 loop /snap/vlc/2344
loop13        7:13   0 251.6M  1 loop /snap/qt513/23
loop14        7:14   0 162.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop16        7:16   0 242.4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/76
loop17        7:17   0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop18        7:18   0 426.5M  1 loop /snap/pycharm-community/252
loop19        7:19   0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12704
loop20        7:20   0 257.1M  1 loop /snap/zoom-client/159
loop21        7:21   0  77.2M  1 loop /snap/discord/128
loop22        7:22   0 241.4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/70
loop24        7:24   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
loop25        7:25   0   6.2M  1 loop /snap/curl/333
loop27        7:27   0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/547
loop28        7:28   0  10.2M  1 loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/105
loop29        7:29   0  65.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
loop30        7:30   0  64.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop31        7:31   0 426.4M  1 loop /snap/pycharm-community/250
loop32        7:32   0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12883
loop33        7:33   0 135.4M  1 loop /snap/whatsapp-for-linux/26
loop34        7:34   0 257.1M  1 loop /snap/zoom-client/158
loop35        7:35   0  70.5M  1 loop /snap/superproductivity/1360
loop36        7:36   0 111.7M  1 loop /snap/whatsapp-for-linux/25
loop37        7:37   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop38        7:38   0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/542
loop39        7:39   0 208.4M  1 loop /snap/code/74
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   650M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   128M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 147.9G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   990M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0  10.6G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0   1.2G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p7 259:7    0    77G  0 part /
```

Comment: Can you post output of 'lsblk'

Answer (score 0):

Hello I didn't understand what you want.
If you want to remove windows here is the solution-
Using ubuntu iso file create a bootable usb ( skip it if you have) you can use disk image mounter on ubuntu and rufus on windows (your choice)
Then restart your device (make sure usb is plugged in) and press F12 while booting, boot from usb
Then just install ubuntu again and keep all files and data ( or you can back it up first)
I hope so your problem is solved :)